# how to write multiple dataframe to multiple sheet of one csv excel file in R?

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataframe

I am trying to write multiple dataframe to a single csv formated file but each in a different sheet of the excel file:

```
write.csv(dataframe1, file = "file1.csv",row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(dataframe2, file = "file2.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

is there any way to specify the sheet along with the csv file in this code and write them all in one file?

thank you in advance,

Comment: with package WriteXLS ? csv is a text file, I really don't think you can have sheets in csv...

Comment: @CathG :yeah right sorry,i meant one excel file with a csv format

Comment: @f.a Do you mean to collapse all dataframes into 1 dataframe, then output into 1 CSV file?

Comment: @zx8754, No I mean to write each dataframe in each sheet of the csv formated excel file

Comment: WriteXLS is the answer. There is no such thing as Excel file with CSV sheets...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. That is the functionality of csv to be just in one sheet so that you can view it either from notepad or any other such software. If you still try to write it would get over ridden. Just try to open a csv and open a new sheet and just write some values and save it. The values which were already there is erased. one excel file in csv format can have only one sheet.

Comment: yeah, right, thank you @Arun Raja , as zx87546 and CathG commented, I could have multiple sheet in a single excel file through WriteXLS

Comment: XLConnect is better. Try that. You can define the number of sheets while writing. getsheets() gives the number of sheets while reading it back.

Answer (score 0):

The xlsx and XLConnect packages will do the trick as well.