# create multiple tab in CSV file through R

Tags: r, csv

I have a query in `R`, for loading data into `.xlsx` multiple tabs we use below code

```
write.xlsx(newtrain, 
           file = 'path/file.xlsx',
           sheetName = 'sheet 1',append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)  
write.xlsx(newtrain, 
           file = 'path/file.xlsx',
           sheetName = 'sheet 2',append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

same way I wanted to create for `.csv` file.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. CSV files don't have tabs. Do you want to write to multiple CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write csv using below code

```
write.csv(MyData, file = "MyData.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

But if you want multiple sheet like xlsx so please refer below link.

[how to write multiple dataframe to multiple sheet of one csv excel file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989917/how-to-write-multiple-dataframe-to-multiple-sheet-of-one-csv-excel-file-in-r)

Comment: How will csv have multiple tabs?

Comment: @Hardikgupta i think he wants to say multiple sheet like xlsx.